# Which admin site is best for disk benchmark questions on Linux?

Tags: discussion, support

If I have a question about development I post it in StackOverflow.  No need to think too much about it.

Today I have a question about tools for benchmarking the speed of disk drives on Linux.  So, taking a quick look at my options I see three possible sites: superuser, unix and serverfault.

Now, if a development question in SO seems to apply to multiple tags, I just add all the possibly matching tags.  But my question today possibly applies to multiples *sites*.  And I don't think I can post easily to multiple sites.  (Can I?)

So I have a question and a suggestion:

Question:  Which site should I use to ask a question about benchmarking disk drive speeds on Linux?

Suggestion:  Consolidate all the admin sites to one site and create more tags on that site.

(To the person who may wish to close this as redundant:  Yes there are other posts discussing the fact that there are too many sites.  But none asks which site is the best for disk benchmarking tools.)

Comment: What do you intend to ask? "best benchmarking s/w" will probably get closed everywhere

Comment: Unix/Linux is probably best for questions *specific* to Unix and Linux, even though those questions might also be on-topic elsewhere on the network. (No, I don't know why there's a separate site, either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already questions that cover that on Server Fault and Super User.  Search first; I suspect if you actually look, you'll find the general topic already has good coverage.

But if you ask a question along the lines of `the best disk benchmarking tool`, then your question will probably be closed as non-constructive.

In any case, the tools you use may be different depending on the point of view.  Is this a home user system or is this enterprise storage?  End user questions go to Super User.  Enterprise storage can be asked about on Server Fault.

Comment: "best **tool** for disk benchmarking **tools**" - sorry something doesn't ring right in this sentence.

Comment: @Sha: That's probably my fault. I hit "improve" on a suggested edit to fix some other stuff without noticing that it messed up the phrasing there. I fixed it back now.

Answer (score 1):

We've reached a point where we do have quite a bit of overlap between sites. SF/AU/UL - all great places to ask such a question (AU only if you're using Ubuntu). If your question was more 'home user' based, then it would be a draw between SU/AU/UL.

Look at all three sites. Which one do you like the most? Which one do you feel would be your best asset for getting answers in the future? In other words, which community would benefit you the most? Likewise, which community would benefit FROM you the most?

While the topics may seem similar, each community is different. Just be sure to search, read the FAQ and most of all look around before posting. Check out what's on the front page of each site's meta if you have time. Figure out which community you'd like to be part of, and then join it.